# What to return when posting a form from a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to MVC and am trying to implement a contact page.
I created a partial view for the contact part and I am adding it on my index page with this line

```
@Html.Partial("_Contact")
```

When my form is submitted my code executes and when the form is not valid I have to return something.
My question is what do I have to return to make it work.
I want to return my model to my contact partial view but I still have to show my index page because the contact part is shown there.
Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

This is the post code:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult _Contact(EmailFormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        var message = new MailMessage();
        var templatePath = path + _configuration.GetSection("Email.PathToHtmlTemplate").Value;
        var smtpHost = _configuration.GetSection("Email.Smtp.Host").Value;
        var smtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(_configuration.GetSection("Email.Smtp.Port").Value);
        var smtpUser = _configuration.GetSection("Email.Smtp.UserName").Value;
        var smtpPass = _configuration.GetSection("Email.Smtp.Password").Value;
        var from = _configuration.GetSection("Email.From").Value;
        var to = _configuration.GetSection("Email.To").Value;
        var cc = _configuration.GetSection("Email.Cc").Value;
        var bcc = _configuration.GetSection("Email.Bcc").Value;
        var subject = _configuration.GetSection("Email.Subject").Value;

        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                  {
                      { "{{NAME}}", model.Name },
                      { "{{TEL}}", model.Telephone },
                      { "{{EMAIL}}", model.Email },
                      { "{{MESSAGE}}", model.Message },
                  };

        dic.ForEach(x => html = html.Replace(x.Key, x.Value));

        foreach (var t in to.Split(';'))
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(t));
        }
        foreach (var t in cc.Split(';'))
        {
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(t));
        }
        foreach (var t in bcc.Split(';'))
        {
            message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(t));
        }
        message.From = new MailAddress(from); 
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = html;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
                             {
                                 UserName = smtpUser,  
                                 Password = smtpPass 
                             };
            smtp.Credentials = credential;
            smtp.Host = smtpHost;
            smtp.Port = smtpPort;
            smtp.Send(message);
            return View("EmailSent");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The index view:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

...

@Html.Partial("_Contact")
```

The contact view:

```
@model EmailFormModel;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contact";
}

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="_Contact" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <!-- Contact Page Section Start -->
    <div id="contact" class="contact-page-sec pt-100 pb-100">
        <div class="container">
            <row>
                <div class="contact-page-sec">
                    <div class="sec-title">
                        <h1>Contacteer ons</h1>
                        <div class="border-shape"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </row>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="contact-info">
                        <div class="contact-info-item">
                            <div class="contact-info-icon">
                                <img src="img/icon/phone.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-info-text">
                                <h2>Telefoon</h2>
                                <span>
                                    <a href='tel:+3245798689'>+(32) 496 56 53 13</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-info">
                        <div class="contact-info-item">
                            <div class="contact-info-icon">
                                <img src="img/icon/envelope.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-info-text">
                                <h2>e-mail</h2>
                                <span>
                                    <a href='mailto:info@vloerwerken-krekelbergh.be'>info@vloerwerken-krekelbergh.be</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-info">
                        <div class="contact-info-item">
                            <div class="contact-info-icon">
                                <img src="img/icon/map-marker.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="contact-info-text">
                                <h2>Adres</h2>
                                <span>Engelstraat 60</span>
                                <span>8211 Aartrijke, België</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-profile">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/vloerwerken-krekelbergh-228041574489932/">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="contact-field">
                        <h2>Schrijf uw bericht</h2>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="single-input-field">
                                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="single-input-field">
                                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email"/>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="single-input-field">
                                <input asp-for="Telephone" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 message-input">
                            <div class="single-input-field">
                                <textarea asp-for="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-input-fieldsbtn" style="clear: both;">
                            <input id="submitBtn" value="Verstuur" type="submit">
                        </div>

                        <div id="info"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Contact Page Section End -->
</form>
```

Comment: I was writing an answer for you but I came across the docs: [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) it explains a lot. It even has an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/validation/sample)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. I am using the Validation Attributes and its working fine. I just want to return that validation to my page. I added the post method to my question

Comment: To help you better I also need to see your view. Can you post the `.cshtml` code for the contact view?

Comment: I updated my question.